# Can't ssh to instance from bastion server

Tags: ssh

I want to ssh into instance in private subnet using bastion server. 
I am using `ssh -A ubuntu@bastionserver` to login to bastion.
Then I am doing `ssh user@privateHost` and it says permission denied (public key).

When I put the instance in public network and try to ssh it works but doesn't work from bastion server. When I run ssh with -v option, I can see that it is trying the key which is the actual key for that private instance. Still it fails.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Please show the sshd config for privateHost.

Comment: perhaps also add ~/.ssh/config related entries for those two hosts.

Comment: Try this instead `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh ubuntu@bastionserver -W %h:%p" user@privateHost`